# Using ggplot2 with columns that have spaces in their names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've the following data frame structure

```
df <- as.data.frame(A)
colnames(df)<- c("Sum of MAE", "Company")
df <- na.omit(df)
df2 <- df[order(df[,1]),]
df2 <- head(df2, n=10)
ggplot(df2, aes_string("Sum of MAE", "Company", group=1) + geom_line())
print(df2)
```

This is the structure of the data

```
 Sum of MAE Company
606   0.030156758080105    COCO
182  0.0600065426668421    APWC
836  0.0602272459239397     EDS
1043 0.0704327240953608    FREE
2722               0.09   VLYWW
1334 0.0900000000000001    IKAN
2420  0.104746328560384     SPU
860   0.106063964745531    ELON
2838  0.108373386847075    WTSL
1721  0.110086738825851    MTSL
```

The ggplot doesnt seem to be working. After a litany of errors the current one I'm getting is

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
1: Sum of
```

Can someone help me getting the ggplot 2 working.

Comment: Share your data as `dput(df2)` so we can see the underlying structure and classes.

Comment: That's huge, can't fit in here.

Comment: Then do `dput(head(df2))` for the first 6 rows. Also, [is this question also you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29127222/903061)? Why the two accounts? As in that question, I'm guessing you need to specify that the `x` axis is Company. By putting it second you will default to the y axis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good reason you should always make sure you have valid column names. First, here's an easier-to-reproduce version of your dataset

```
df2 <- data.frame(`Sum of MAE` = c(0.030156758080105, 0.0600065426668421, 
   0.0602272459239397, 0.0704327240953608, 0.09, 0.0900000000000001, 
   0.104746328560384, 0.106063964745531, 0.108373386847075, 0.110086738825851
   ), Company = c("COCO", "APWC", "EDS", "FREE", "VLYWW", "IKAN", "SPU", "ELON", 
   "WTSL", "MTSL"), check.names=F)

ggplot(df2, aes_string("Sum of MAE", "Company", group=1) + geom_line())
# Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
# 1: Sum of
#         ^
```

The problem is that `aes_string()` uses `parse()` to turn your text expression into a proper R symbol that can be resolved within the data.frame. When you parse "Sum of MAE" that's not valid R syntax -- that is, it doesn't resolve to a single nice symbol name. If you use "bad" names like that, you can escape them with the back-tick to treat the expression (spaces and all) as a symbol. So you can do

```
ggplot(df2, aes_string("`Sum of MAE`", "Company", group=1)) + geom_line()
# or
ggplot(df2, aes(`Sum of MAE`, Company, group=1)) + geom_line()
```

but really it would be better to stick to using valid column names for your data.frame rather than bypassing the checks with colnames().

If you were changing the column names to get "nicer" axis labels, you should probably do what with `xlab()` instead. For example

```
df3 <- data.frame(df2)
names(df3)
# [1] "Sum.of.MAE" "Company" 
ggplot(df3, aes(Sum.of.MAE, Company, group=1)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    xlab("Sum of MAE values")
```

Comment: I changed the name to "Sum" and the error that i get now is Error in aes_string("Sum", "Company", group = 1) + geom_line() : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Well, you also have parenthesis problems in your original example. Try the code I wrote and compare it to what you are running.

Comment: Thanks this code seems to be working, in sense I'm not getting any errors. But I don't see a any plots in the plot section of R Studio. Any ideas why?

Comment: No. The code i've written above works just fine for me and I do not use RStudio.

Comment: I was also able to produce the plots with this code using RStudio on Windows 7.

Comment: I find renaming column names to have spaces before ggplotting quite useful as I can rename the columns to be properly formatted in the figure. Backticks work well in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what you want to plot, here is a start (and others might understand better).

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(" 
                                606   0.030156758080105    COCO
                                182  0.0600065426668421    APWC
                                836  0.0602272459239397     EDS
                                1043 0.0704327240953608    FREE
                                2722               0.09   VLYWW
                                1334 0.0900000000000001    IKAN
                                2420  0.104746328560384     SPU
                                860   0.106063964745531    ELON
                                2838  0.108373386847075    WTSL
                                1721  0.110086738825851    MTSL"))
colnames(df) <- c("sum", "MAE", "Company")
ggplot(df, aes(x=Company, y=MAE, group = 1)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]